# Selected range of Excel cells passed to an argument "as Variant" of a VBA function, then passed to an method of an ATL object in c++

Tags: c++, excel, vba, atl

This question arose from the following question :

[Chaining methods of ATL/COM objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804955/chaining-methods-of-atl-com-objects)

Let's say I have a instance `MyObj1` of an ATL/COM class `TheClass` of a dll exposed to vba, and a method `TheMethod` of `TheClass`.

In VBA, I have a function

```
Public Function func(x as Variant) as Variant
    '... something
    MyObj1.TheMethod( x )
    '... other things
End Function
```

This function is used in excel, and I pass an excel range of cell to it. At debug in VBA, x is seen of vba type "`Variant/Object/Range`", and has a "`Value2`" of vba type "`Variant/Variant`", and if the range is for instance a rectangle containing expty cells and doubles in excel, when `Value2` is unfolded (still in watch in debug in vba), it is composed of `Variant`'s of types "`Variant/Double`" or "`Variant/Empty`". It is this "core" "`Value2`" `Variant` that I would like to isolate in the next step, **in c++**.

At the next step, at debug in c++ at the entry of the ATL method `TheMethod` of signature

```
STDMETHODIMP TheClass::TheMethod( VARIANT* var_in )
```

`var_in` (which received the latter `x`) is seen having a `vt` equal to `VT_DISPATCH`. This guy carries for sure (even if I don't know) all the stuff already carried by the latter `x`, but I would like to know how to isolate the "`Value2`" part of it to catch it and work with it, as only the `Value2` part interests me.

Let me say that I know that rather than doing it in c++, I could do this in vba :

```
Public Function func(x as Variant) as Variant
    '... something
    MyObj1.TheMethod( x.Value2 )
    '... other things
End Function
```

but **I don't want to resort to such thing in VBA**.

Comment: Well, that `IDispatch` pointer packed into the variant is, obviously, that of a [`Range` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx). To do the equivalent of `x.Value2` in C++, you would either `#import` Excel's TLB and use generated wrappers, or use late binding, perhaps with the help of `CComDispatchDriver`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so as Igor Tandetnik suggested, i did something like :

```
VARIANT * pVARIANT_IN_EXTENSION = new VARIANT() ;
VariantInit(pVARIANT_IN_EXTENSION);
IDispatch * piDisp = pVARIANT_IN->pdispVal ;
::DISPPARAMS invokeparams = {0} ;
HRESULT hRes = piDisp->Invoke(0, IID_NULL, 0, DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET,&invokeparams, pVARIANT_IN_EXTENSION, NULL, NULL);
```

to get the real "array variant" (of vt equal to VT_ARRAY) packed into the VT_DISPATCH variant pVARIANT_IN.

I will later give a try to the import of Excel's type library.